# Difference between "if x" and "if x is not None"

Tags: python, boolean

It appears that `if x` is almost like short-hand for the longer `if x is not None` syntax. Are they functionally identical or are there cases where for a given value of `x` the two would evaluate differently?

I would assume the behavior should also be identical across Python implementations - but if there are subtle differences it would be great to know.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the following cases:

```
test = False 
test = "" 
test = 0
test = 0.0 
test = []
test = () 
test = {} 
test = set()
```

the `if` test will differ:

```
if test: #False

if test is not None: #True
```

This is the case because `is` tests for identity, meaning

```
test is not None
```

is equivalent to

```
id(test) == id(None) #False
```

therefore

```
(test is not None) is (id(test) != id(None)) #True
```

Comment: And in even more. *All* empty collections and 0-equivalents are (usually) falsy.

Comment: collections.deque, collections.defaultdict, collections.namedtuple, collections.OrderedDict...  also anything with the magic methods `__bool__` or `__nonzero__` returning false.

Comment: and to expand upon the 0-equivalents: Decimal(0), 0+0j, 0.0, etc all evaluate to false.

Answer (score 37):

The former tests trueness, whereas the latter tests for identity with `None`. Lots of values are false, such as `False`, `0`, `''`, and `None`, but only `None` is `None`.

Answer (score 6):

```
x = 0
if x: ...  # False
if x is not None: ... # True
```

Answer (score 5):

`if x` checks if `x` is considered as `True`.

In Python, everything has a boolean value (`True`/`False`).

Values that are considered as `False`:

- `False`, `None`
- `0`, `0.0`, `0j`
- `[]`, `()`, `{}`
- `''`
- Other instances that signal to Python that they are empty

Other values are considered as `True`. For example, `[False]`, `('hello')`, `'hello'` are considered as `True` (because they are not empty).

When using `if x is not None`, you are checking if `x` is not `None`, but it can be `False` or other instances that are considered as `False`.

```py
>>> x = None
>>> if not x:print x # bool(None) is False
None
>>> if x == None:print x
None
>>> x = False
>>> if not x:print x
False
>>> if x == None:print x
```

Finally, note that `True` and `False` are respectively equal to `1` and `0`:

```py
>>> True + 1
2
>>> False + 1
1
>>> range(1, 5)[False]
1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if x:
    # Evaluates for any defined non-False value of x
if not x:
    # Evaluates for any defined False value of x
if x is None:
    # Evaluates for any instances of None
```

None is its own type, which happens to be False. "if not x" evaluates if x = None, only because None is  False.

There aren't any subtle differences that I know of but there are exact methods to test for use for positivity/negativity in exact situations. Mixing them can work in some situations, but can lead to problems if they're not understood.

```
if x is True:
    # Use for checking for literal instances of True
if x is False:
    # Use for checking for literal instances of False
if x is None:
    # Use for checking for literal instances of None
if x:
    # Use for checking for non-negative values
if not x:
    # Use for checking for negative values
    # 0, "", None, False, [], (), {} are negative, all others are True
```